# How do I get number of arrays from an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have a JSON webservice in the following format.

```
 { Name:['a','b'], Name:['cd','ef'], Age:{...}, Address:{...} }.
```

Here I have **2 arrays & 2 objects** inside an object and these (array & objects) numbers may vary. What I need is, how can I get the number of Arrays alone from the main Object? There may exist another way to solve my problem but I need my code to be in a .JS (javascript file).

**When I tried:**

```
Object.keys(mainobject).length;
```

It gives total count of array + objects in main object.

Comment: Do you need IE8 support?

Comment: Parse the JSON, iterate over it's properties and increase a counter for each property whose value is an array.

Comment: I don't think you can have two `Name` keys in the same object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Length of Javascript Object (ie. Associative Array)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-javascript-object-ie-associative-array)

Comment: @c.P.u1 You can. The latest occurrence of a key will overwrite any preceding one.

Comment: No @frenche, i need IE 10 support only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var data = { Name:['a','b'], OtherName:['cd','ef'], Age:{a: 12}, Address:{a: 'asdf'} }

var numberOfArrays = Object.keys(data).filter(function(key) {
    return data[key] instanceof Array; //or Array.isArray(data[key]) if the array was created in another frame
}).length;

alert(numberOfArrays);
```

**Note: This won't work in older versions of IE**

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/32fsM/)

To make it work with browsers that don't support it, use the shims from MDN:

[**Object.keys**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

[**Array.filter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Thanks for the help @c.P.u1. And is it possible to count depending on particular array names.

Comment: That doesn't work in old IE; if all you serve is mobile and new browsers that may be fine.

Comment: @user2546074, the key parameter in `filter` holds the name of the property. For e.g., if you wanted a count of arrays with name 'OtherName': `return data[key] instanceof Array && key === 'OtherName'`

Answer (score 1):

I'd write something to count all the types

```
var obj = {
    k1: ['a','b'], k2: ['cd','ef'],
    k3: 0, k4: 1,
    k5: {a:'b'},
    k6: new Date(),
    k7: "foo"
};

function getType(obj) {
    var type = Object.prototype.toString.call(obj).slice(8, -1);
    if (type === 'Object') return obj.constructor.name;
    return type;
}

function countTypes(obj) {
    var k, hop = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty,
        ret = {}, type;
    for (k in obj) if (hop.call(obj, k)) {
        type = getType(obj[k]);
        if (!ret[type]) ret[type] = 1;
        else ++ret[type];
    }
    return ret;
}

var theTypes = countTypes(obj);
// Object {Array: 2, Number: 2, Object: 1, Date: 1, String: 1}
```

Now if I wanted to know the number of *Arrays* only

```
var numArrays = theTypes.Array || 0; // 2 Arrays in this example
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try checking the type of each member of your object.

```
var count = 0;
for (var foo in mainobject) {
    if (foo instanceof Array) count++;
}
```

Now all you have to do is read the value of `count`.